# Run a script multiple time with random arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterable

I am trying to run the script multiple times, and I have 3 random arguments that should change every run.

```
m=np.linspace(1,15,50)
rand_m=random.choice(m)
n=np.linspace(1,10,11)
rand_n=random.choice(n)
o=np.linspace(50,150,50)
rand_o=random.choice(o)
```

I've tried

```
For _ in range (10): or for _ in itertools.repeat(None,10):
    # do something
# end with .txt
```

this way does the 10 runs but with the same values of rand_m,rand_n,rand_o. So, I need a way to keep these random values changing every run. (running it simultaneously not required)

Comment: put them inside the loop so they are set on each run

Comment: Thanks, those were imported from a different .py file. so, when I tried it inside the loop, it gave the same values, after editing, It works now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems simple enough, why not place rand_m,rand_n,rand_o in the for loop:

```py
for _ in range(0,10):
    m = np.linspace(1, 15, 50)
    rand_m = random.choice(m)
    n = np.linspace(1, 10, 11)
    rand_n = random.choice(n)
    o = np.linspace(50, 150, 50)
    rand_o = random.choice(o)
```